# Laravel LengthAwarePaginator where query

Tags: php, laravel

I have LengthAwarePaginator in variable `dataTypeContent`, when I use `where` he do query only on first page. But I need on all pages and return new filtered items by `where`.

```
$dataTypeContent->where('category_id', 48);

LengthAwarePaginator {#303 ▼
    #total: 283
    #lastPage: 19
    #items: Collection {#1 ▶}
    #perPage: 15
    #currentPage: 1
    #path: "/admin/products"
    #query: []
    #fragment: null
    #pageName: "page"
}
```

More code: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.1/src/Http/Controllers/VoyagerBaseController.php

How I can do `where` on all pages?

Comment: can you show more of your code.

Comment: @ilubis done...

Comment: can you more specified which method are your getting trouble with ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your variable `$dataTypeContent = $someQuery->paginate();`

You should use `where` before `paginate()`. `$dataTypeContent = $someQuery->where()->paginate();`

Comment: I can't use `where` before paginate. Please see: https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/blob/1.1/src/Http/Controllers/VoyagerBaseController.php

Comment: can you give details which line you need where?

Comment: method index, line 31

Comment: There is `$query` variable, you can chain every thing you want here, such as `where`